# CSS selector for showing descendants doesn't work properly

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

my html is (only headers)

```
<div id="msg_wrapper">
    <div class="msg_header media unread>
      <a class="pull-left"></a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="side" class="pull-right">
      <div id="sent_at">
        <div class="timeago" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="msg_header_side">
        <div id="msg_header_icons">
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the css is

```
    .media.unread:hover + #side  #msg_header_side{
    visibility: visible;
    }

    #sent_at {
        float:right;
    }
    .msg_header{
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #msg_header_side{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #msg_header_icons{

        background-color: transparent;
        float: right;
    }

    #side{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #msg_wrapper{
        position: relative;
    }
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp93q/2/) with similiar tags and I've added colors to explain the situation

blue (`#msg_header_side`) is a section with options that should appear when hover on any part of yellow (`.msg_header`) 
problem is that the current selector (the best I can do) shows blue only if the the mouse cursor is on yellow.

like this (screenshot didn't capture mouse cursor - it's on yellow):

[image]

when the cursor is on red (`#side`) - blue disappears

like this (screenshot didn't capture mouse cursor - it's on red):
[image]

my selector is  `.media.unread:hover + #side  #msg_header_side`
which how I understand it is "class of media and unread when hovered and side with msg_header_side as child will have visibility:visible.
Doesn't work very well..

Comment: `.media.unread:hover + #side #msg_header_side` matches `#msg_header_side` descandant of `#side` immediately preceded by a sibling `.media.unread:hover` according to [pattern-matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching). This is not the definition you have given.

Comment: so is there a way to fix the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an additional selector to match against `#msg_header_side` as descandant of `#side:hover`

```
.media.unread:hover + #side #msg_header_side, #side:hover #msg_header_side
```

Hope that is you wanted.

Comment: thats pretty close, but that also does that #side:hover shows #msg_header_side. I need to show blue (on jsfiddle) on yellow and red. your solution gives yellow or red.

Comment: @Foxedd - As #side is not a descandant of .media, .media lose :hover state whenever your cursor is on #side. Putting #side in .media will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure about the "+" sign, but this should some the problem:

```
.media.unread:hover,
#side  #msg_header_side{
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: no, that's completely wrong. The comma specifies that the second part is a separate selector. Not what the OP wants at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but i think you want to take element1 wich has yellow background and element2 which has a red background and if you hover both of them element3 which has a blue color should appear. First of all you should realize that your yellow element doesn't surround a red element and since they are siblings stacking order tells us that red one is normally on top of its previous sibling which has to be the yellow. By entering the red element you leaves the yellow one and your selector:

***ORIGINAL:***

```
.media.unread:hover + #side  #msg_header_side {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

tells the browser show us the element with #msg_header_side(blue) id which has to be the child of #side(red) element if #side's(red) sibling with classes .media.unread(yellow) is hovered.

to tell the browser to show the element if also the red element is hovered you have to append code to your first line and change it as follows:

***ALTERED:***

```
.media.unread:hover + #side  #msg_header_side, #side:hover  #msg_header_side {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

as you see only first line was altered.

P.S. i'm sorry for the mess i wrote:) you can also reconsider your selector naming there are so many classes and ids it could sure be better.